# Chrome trying to load http site over https

Tags: google-chrome, http, https

So we have a site that does not have an ssl certificate and normally loads fine over http (works in firefox, chrome canary, safari etc) but when loading the site on Chrome v 44 it cant find any of the resources because it is trying to serve them over https.

So the html loads but no styling or scripts etc.

We think this is happening after a chrome update.  In the console, all the resources have this error

> net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: I am having the same problem with version 44 of Chrome. All the internal links of my site (including links to images, style sheets) are shown as https in chrome view source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is in wordpress, I have the solution. 
Just place

> $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;

in your themes's functions.php.
At least it worked for me...

Comment: This worked as a temporary fix but there is a WooCommerce update available which says it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is Chrome HSTS [Chrome HSTS](http://www.chromium.org/hsts)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Ive had a look on there at the issue list and it seems someone else has got the same problem.